# System UI Visibility in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hey Flutter community!

In my app I want the system status bar to **always** be visible, while keeping the system navigation bar hidden by default. It should only appear when the user swipes upward and then auto-hide after a few seconds.

In simpler terms, I'd like the status bar always visible and the navigation bar to behave like 'SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky'.

Currently, the closest I've got is using the following code, but the navigation bar stays always visible after swiping up:

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
  overlays: [
    SystemUiOverlay.top,
  ],
  SystemUiMode.manual,
);
```

Unfortunately, 'immersiveSticky' doesn't work with overlays.

I'd appreciate any helps on implementing this behaviour.

Thanks for your help!